# Debugging infinite digest for $rootScope.$apply in unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a simple test for my UserService that calls my ApiService. I'm using a third party API SDK so I can't use `$httpBackend` directly, but I've set it up so that at least for now empty data is returned from the API:

```
// ApiService mock
beforeEach(module($provide =>
    $provide.factory("ApiService", $q => ({
        request: () => $q.resolve({data: {}}),
    }))
));

// Test
describe("registerUser", () => {
    it("registers user", () => {
        const registerId = "registerId";
        $window.SDK = {credentials: {registerId}};

        UserService.registerUser("socialId", "email");
        $rootScope.$apply();

        expect(UserService.registerId).to.equal(registerId);
    });
});

// Implementation
function UserService(ApiService, $window) {
    let service = {};
    service.registerUser = (socialId, email) => {
        return ApiService.request("registerUser", {socialId, email}).then(response => {
            service.registerId = $window.SDK.credentials.registerId;
        });
    };
    return service;
}
```

Essentially the UserService calls ApiService which calls the SDK. This sets the internal `registerId` which gets set on UserService.

I am using `$rootScope.$apply` in order to resolve the promise. In fact, if I do call it, I confirm that `registerId` is appropriately set. *However*, I get `[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

If I don't use `$rootScope.$apply` the promise is never resolved and `registerId` never gets set.

Is there any other way to resolve the promise or mock this API? In general, how can I properly debug what would be causing the infinite digest cycle from this `$rootScope.$apply`? It doesn't seem to be calling `registerUser` in a loop.

Comment: Posting the entire error message with call stack may help. I don't see any part that would cry 'infinite digest'. This `module($provide => $provide.factory...)` is bad, Angular don't like `config` blocks to return anything. `UserService` isn't a service and can't access any dependencies, they should be `undefined`. I would suggest Sinon for non-Angular HTTP mocking.

Comment: @estus thanks for the suggestions; more research leads me to believe that this is not actually part of the code that's here at all but has something to do with a separate service, `.run` and `ui-router`. Do you have an example of using sinon for non-Angular HTTP mocking?

Comment: @estus I also don't understand what you mean by `UserService isn't a service and can't access any dependencies` ... I didn't include the part where I inject `UserService` in the test, but I do.

Comment: That's true, the true offender may be in the code that you didn't post, and a router is most frequently contributing part in infinite digests. It is better to not have the router-related modules to be loaded in specs that don't test routing.

Comment: There's a plenty of posts on SO on Sinon. It isn't specific to Angular at all, and the only thing that is specific to Jasmine is that Sinon mocks (including [HTTP](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server)) should be torn down in `afterEach*`.

Comment: @estus removing the router configuration works great; thanks for pointing me in that direction. Only thing that concerns me slightly is that those blocks end up untested, but since it's essentially just configuration and no logic there is not really anything to test anyway. I think this could be helpful for people running into this issue with testing so it may be possible for you to craft an answer

Comment: Sure, added an answer. I don't have a good example of router testing at hand, but it is really straightforward once the routing is isolated in separate module. Router provider methods are just spied and matched against expected route configuration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true offender may be be situated in non-relevant code, a router is most frequently contributing part in infinite digests.

Unit testing supposes that a unit is tested in isolation from other moving parts. It is better to not have the router-related modules to be loaded in specs that aren't involved in router testing (the same applies to any other units that affect the entire app).

In this case a routing module (e.g. `app.router`) depends on router module (`ui.router` or `ngRoute`) and may be loaded only by top module (`app`), not by the others.

`app.router` unit itself may contain `config` and `run` blocks that set up routing and be tested by mocking router providers (`$routeProvider` in the case of `ngRouter`) and spying methods that are used for route definitions(`$routeProvider.when`, etc).